# Multiple lines in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, label

```
func setTitleLabel(text: String) {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)

    titleLabel.text = text

    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2

    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 22)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 28/255, blue: 194/255, alpha: 1)

    titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.snp_top).offset(20)
    }
}
```

I have such kind of function for my label, but actually my label text for label is long. What I can do? I wrote this:

```
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
```

but this didn't help me

Comment: How does it look right now?

Comment: @ShamasS, just one line of text

Comment: What is the frame? I guess the height of the label is not enough and that's why you see only the first line.

Comment: Set the height constraint as flexible.

Comment: I don't see where you are constraining the width of the label - you need to do this, otherwise it will simply expand sideways.  Also, it's conventional to set `numberOfLines` to 0 for a multiline label with dynamic text. Also, it may help to update the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of the label when it is laid out

Comment: thanks guys, i fix this)

Answer (score 0):

Try to also constraint the width of the label. If you don't, it will use its intrinsic content size and the label will become wider so the text can fit in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class to stretch it's font to current label size [Class](https://github.com/VolodymyrKhmil/BBBLibs/tree/master/BBBAutoresizedFontLabel)

All you need to do is to tell, that you label is of this class. After that your labels font will automatically be updated to fit into it's rect.

As well there is some IBInspectable properties that can help to setup behavior .

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `numberOfLines` like below

```
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
@IBOutlet weak var feedNoteLabel: UILabel!
```

and add this code into viewDidLoad()

```
feedNoteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
feedNoteLabel.sizeToFit()
feedNoteLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
```